# want to get number of tweets of a keyword per a day using Keyword Insights of Twitter api

Tags: ruby, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to get number of tweets of a keyword per a day.

I want to use Keyword Insights of Twitter api using Ruby. : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/audiences/api-reference/keyword-insights

I have tryed to write code. But I got such following error.

```
`<main>': undefined method `keywords' for #<Twitter::REST::Client:0x00000000062837b8> (NoMethodError)
```

The Ruby code is following.

```
require "twitter"
require 'yaml'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
Encoding.default_external = 'UTF-8'

  @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = 'xxxx'
    config.consumer_secret     = 'xxxx'
    config.access_token        = 'xxxx-xxxx'
    config.access_token_secret = 'xxxx'
  end

# @client.update('hoge')
# => succes.
@client.insights.keywords.search("DAY","Ruby")
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other poster mentioned, there's no Ads API support in the `twitter` gem, but Twitter has a `twitter-ads` gem you can [obtain on Github](https://github.com/twitterdev/twitter-ruby-ads-sdk). Note that you will also need to have your app tokens whitelisted for access to the Ads API. You can apply for that via [Twitter's developer site](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/general/guides/getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

Ruby twitter gem doesn't has any method to retrieve insights (checked on documentation). You can implement your own method following the twitter api reference: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/audiences/api-reference/insights